# Copy center of mass of an object to another object

Tags: objects, geometry, 3d-cursor

I'm trying to mod a model for a game. There's no way of editing the position in space in the game, so I need to basically copy the position of the center of mass of the old object to the new one. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- Select source object > <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*
- Select target object  > <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Set Origin > *Origin to Cursor*.

---

Blender <2.8:

- Select source object > <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*
- Select target object  > <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Center to Cursor*.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on how you solved it? What mode you were on, what keyboard shortcuts you used?

Comment: In object mode. I put all models in their respected spaces that I needed them to be in. I then selected the object that I needed the "center of mass from" then did cursor to selection on that object (shift S), then I selected my new object that I needed with an offset center of mass, and then use (Ctrl+alt+shift+c) to then do origin to 3d cursor. Now when i put the model in game, it will be in a new position which fits further away then the original shape did.

Comment: Nice, could you edit your question and add those detail there, please.